# Safari domainA hosting iframe in domainB, links back to domainA in new tab, no cookie is sent

Tags: cookies, safari

I have a website 'domainA'. User logs in and gets cookie.  In that website I'm using a calendar in an iframe from 'domainB'.  The calendar has links with target _blank that refer back to 'domainA'.

In all browsers except Safari it works fine.
In Safari the new tab opens but Safari doesn't set the cookie so the user is not logged in.  If you click into the url and hit enter the page will reload and send the cookie.
If you just hit 'refresh' it won't send the cookie.

How can I get safari to send the cookie when loading the link from this iframe?